# Getting a list of all JADE containers

Tags: javaagents, agents-jade

I want to get a list of all containers in the current platform. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508477/jade-agent-containers) is similar, but the answer is obsolete and the method is by querying to the AMS agent. Is there any simpler way out than to communicate via ACL messages which I think is complex, there should be a way out to get a simple list of containers. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using the AMSSubscriber class and listen to the events when a container is added or removed. See sample code below:

```
public class myAgent extends Agent {

  private ArrayList<ContainerID> availableContainers = new ArrayList<ContainerID>();

  /**
   * Agent initializations
  **/
  protected void setup() {

    AMSSubscriber subscriber = new AMSSubscriber(){
      protected void installHandlers(Map handlers){
        EventHandler addedHandler = new EventHandler(){
          public void handle(Event event){
              AddedContainer addedContainer = (AddedContainer) event;
              availableContainers.add(addedContainer.getContainer());
          }
        };
    handlers.put(IntrospectionVocabulary.ADDEDCONTAINER,addedHandler);


        EventHandler removedHandler = new EventHandler(){
          public void handle(Event event){
              RemovedContainer removedContainer = (RemovedContainer) event;
              ArrayList<ContainerID> temp = new ArrayList<ContainerID>(availableContainers);
              for(ContainerID container : temp){
                  if(container.getID().equalsIgnoreCase(removedContainer.getContainer().getID()))
                      availableContainers.remove(container);
              }
          }
        };
        handlers.put(IntrospectionVocabulary.REMOVEDCONTAINER,removedHandler);
      }
    };
    addBehaviour(subscriber);
  }
}
```

Reference: 1) Developing multi-agent systems with JADE
 By Fabio Luigi Bellifemine, Giovanni Caire, Dominic Greenwood (page 111)
2) [Jade API](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/domain/introspection/package-summary.html)

Comment: how do i get to know the list of available containers? It isnt allowing me to access the int size() since it is a private member. What to do?

Comment: add a public setter/getter to the ArrayList. For example:                public int getAvailableContainersSize(){return availableContainers.size();}

Comment: i am still not getting how to display the list of all containers, please could you help me where to place the code and what...

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jade.devel/329) you might get some idea on how to implement.